# Deleting mail without selecting next one in Yosemite

Tags: mail.app, macos

Is there any hotkey to delete mail in Mail.app without selecting next message in Yosemite?

In Mavericks it was "Option + backspace" (http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14900?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), but this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Weird that you say that doesn't work, because the Help file still specifies holding Option while deleting to not select the next message. Also Backspace does not exist on a Mac keyboard. ;)

Comment: ok, "Delete" key then, but it still doesn't work for me? Does it for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't.